# npm package error not resolving error occured due to babel

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start, npm-package

ERROR in ./node_modules/folder-structure-display/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules\folder-structure-display\index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (4:5):

2 |
3 | const Folder = ({ name, children, iconcolor }) => (

> 4 |     <div style={{ marginLeft: '25px' }}>
> |     ^
> 5 |         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style={{ display: "inline-flex" }} viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="20px" height="20px"><path d="M 5 4 C 3.3544268 4 2 5.3555411 2 7 L 2 16 L 2 26 L 2 43 C 2 44.644459 3.3544268 46 5 46 L 45 46 C 46.645063 46 48 44.645063 48 43 L 48 26 L 48 16 L 48 11 C 48 9.3549372 46.645063 8 45 8 L 18 8 C 18.08657 8 17.96899 8.000364 17.724609 7.71875 C 17.480227 7.437136 17.179419 6.9699412 16.865234 6.46875 C 16.55105 5.9675588 16.221777 5.4327899 15.806641 4.9628906 C 15.391504 4.4929914 14.818754 4 14 4 L 5 4 z M 5 6 L 14 6 C 13.93925 6 14.06114 6.00701 14.308594 6.2871094 C 14.556051 6.5672101 14.857231 7.0324412 15.169922 7.53125 C 15.482613 8.0300588 15.806429 8.562864 16.212891 9.03125 C 16.619352 9.499636 17.178927 10 18 10 L 45 10 C 45.562937 10 46 10.437063 46 11 L 46 13.1875 C 45.685108 13.07394 45.351843 13 45 13 L 5 13 C 4.6481575 13 4.3148915 13.07394 4 13.1875 L 4 7 C 4 6.4364589 4.4355732 6 5 6 z M 5 15 L 45 15 C 45.56503 15 46 15.43497 46 16 L 46 26 L 46 43 C 46 43.562937 45.562937 44 45 44 L 5 44 C 4.4355732 44 4 43.563541 4 43 L 4 26 L 4 16 C 4 15.43497 4.4349698 15 5 15 z" fill={`${iconcolor ? iconcolor : 'currentcolor'}`} /><span style={{ paddingLeft: 5 }}>{name}
> 6 |         {children && (
> 7 |             <div style={{ marginLeft: '5px' }}>

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
at instantiate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:60:32)
at constructor (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:355:12)
at Parser.raise (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3204:19)
at Parser.expectOnePlugin (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3250:18)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11196:18)
at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10841:23)
at Parser.parseUpdate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10824:21)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10800:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10638:61)
at Parser.parseExprOps (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10643:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10620:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10581:21)
at D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10551:39
at Parser.allowInAnd (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12231:12)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10551:17)
at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11464:28)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11115:23)
at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10841:23)
at Parser.parseUpdate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10824:21)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10800:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10638:61)
at Parser.parseExprOps (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10643:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10620:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10581:21)
at Parser.parseFunctionBody (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11891:24)
at Parser.parseArrowExpression (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11873:10)
at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11476:12)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11115:23)
at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10841:23)
at Parser.parseUpdate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10824:21)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10800:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10638:61)
at Parser.parseExprOps (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10643:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10620:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10581:21)
at D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10551:39
at Parser.allowInAnd (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12226:16)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10551:17)
at Parser.parseVar (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13206:91)
at Parser.parseVarStatement (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13047:10)
at Parser.parseStatementContent (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12630:23)
at Parser.parseStatementLike (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12535:17)
at Parser.parseModuleItem (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12512:17)
at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13136:36)
at Parser.parseBlockBody (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13129:10)
at Parser.parseProgram (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12411:10)
at Parser.parseTopLevel (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12401:25)
at Parser.parse (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14297:10)
at parse (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14317:26)
at parser (D:\Visual Studio\react js\protfolio\node_modules@babel\core\lib\parser\index.js:41:34)

I try many thing use chatgpt  still facing these error actually i am creating a npm package and while installing in my real app its not working and showing these error

Comment: I suggest moving your actual question to the top and then trim off most of the error stack, to shorten the content.  Also, it's not clear why the SVG code is included.